# Is it more efficient to bind multiple events, or to bind one event with a switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, event-handling

I have a number of events that I want to bind as a delegate to the document object, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.create-post', Fti.Modals.createPostModal.open);
$(document).on('click', '.flag', Fti.modalHelper.openFlagModal);
$(document).on('click', '.login', Fti.Modals.loginModal.open);
$(document).on('click', '.register', Fti.Modals.registerModal.open);
```

with some creative refactoring, i did this:

**option 1.**

```
var eventTriggers = [
    {
        element: '.create-post',
        event: Fti.Modals.createPostModal.open
    },{
        element: '.flag',
        event: Fti.modalHelper.openFlagModal
    },{
        element: '.login',
        event: Fti.Modals.loginModal.open
    },{
        element: '.register',
        event: Fti.Modals.registerModal.open
    }
];
for(var i = i, len = eventTriggers.length; i < len; i++){
    $(document).on('click', eventTriggers[i].element, eventTriggers[i].event)
}
```

i am wondering if it might be better to just bind one event to the document object and perform a switch-case based on the event target, like this:

**option 2.**

```
var eventTriggers = [
    {
        element: '.create-post',
        event: Fti.Modals.createPostModal.open
    },{
        element: '.flag',
        event: Fti.modalHelper.openFlagModal
    },{
        element: '.login',
        event: Fti.Modals.loginModal.open
    },{
        element: '.register',
        event: Fti.Modals.registerModal.open
    }
];

var elements = eventTriggers.map(function(item){
    return item.element;
});

$(document).on('click', elements.join(','), function(e){
    var $target = $(e.target)
    for(var i = 0, len = eventTriggers.length; i < len; i++){
        if($target.hasClass(eventTriggers[i].element.substr(1))){
            eventTriggers[i].event.call(e.target);
        }
   }
});
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or experience as to which option would perform better?

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple listener for flexibility. In case you need to detach/remove one it will not affect others.

Comment: In my specific use case, the events that are being bound in the manner are permanent fixtures on the page and at no time will they need to be detached.  Aside from this case, is there a different scenario to support the need for multiple listeners.  Also, I am looking for an answer as related to efficiency and performance

Answer (score 0):

The performance difference seems to be negligible at about 10% depending on your browser. In webkit browsers adding a single event listener seems to take less than one millisecond (your four events sometimes rounds to taking 1ms to to attach). [Running this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NiklasBr/xb75yLna/) with 100k iterations will take approximately 5 to 7 seconds on an i5 CPU.

Unless you keep doing attaching a lot of events like this all the time it seems like a case of premature optimisation. Consider using other the `ID` selector rather than the `class` selector if possible because that might save you more time.

```
<a class="create-post">c</a><a class="flag">f</a><a class="login">l</a><a class="register">r</a>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var iterations = 100000;
    var simple = 0;
    var trigger = 0;
    var eventTriggers = [{
        element: '.create-post',
        event: function () {}
    }, {
        element: '.flag',
        event: function () {}
    }, {
        element: '.login',
        event: function () {}
    }, {
        element: '.register',
        event: function () {}
    }];

    var mt = (new Date).getTime();
    var iteration = 0;
    while (iteration < iterations) {
        $(document).on('click', '.create-post', function () {});
        $(document).on('click', '.flag', function () {});
        $(document).on('click', '.login', function () {});
        $(document).on('click', '.register', function () {});
        iteration++;
    }
    simple = (new Date).getTime() - mt;


    var mt = (new Date).getTime();
    var iteration = 0;
    while (iteration < iterations) {
        for (var i = 0; i < eventTriggers.length; i++) {
            $(document).on('click', eventTriggers[i].element, eventTriggers[i].event);
        }
        iteration++;
    }
    trigger = (new Date).getTime() - mt;

    console.log('simple: ' + simple + 'ms');
    console.log('trigger: ' + trigger + 'ms');
    console.log('diff: ' + (simple - trigger) + 'ms at ' + iterations + ' iterations');
});
</script>
```